# Bootstrap 5 footer isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am creating a website with bootstrap 5, HTML, and CSS. I noticed that when I reduce the size of the screen the columns in the footer don't line up. When the screen is mobile-sized and desktop-sized the columns in the footer line up, but when the screen is tablet-sized and laptop-sized the columns in the footer don't line up.

### This is what the tablet-sized screen looks like [image]

### This is what the desktop-sized screen looks like [image]

### Test.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    

    <!-- FOOTER SECTION START -->
    <footer class="bg-dark text-white " id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
            <h4>About Us</h4>
            <hr />
            <p>We are skilled IT professionals who specialize in solving a range of problems that our clients may face in the realm of IT.

            </p>
            <!-- FACEBOOK SECTION -->
            <a href="">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- INSTAGRAM SECTION  -->
            <a href="">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
            
            
            </a>

            <!-- TWITTER SECTION -->
            <a href="">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
              
            <!-- LINKEDIN SECTION -->
            </a>
            <!-- <a href="#">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
            </a> -->

            <!-- WHATSAPP SECTION -->
            <!-- <a href="#">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
            </a> -->
              
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
            <h4>Quick Links</h4>
            <hr />
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a> </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
            <h4>Privacy and Terms</h4>
            <hr />
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Terms & Coniditions</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">API Documentation</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
            <h4>Contact Info</h4>
            <hr />
            <p class="text-white">
              City, State 12345 <br />
              Call Us Now 123-456-7890 <br />
              example@email.com
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-dark text-white text-center py-4" id="copyright">
        Copyright &copy; 2023 . All Rights Reserved.
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- FOOTER SECTION CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
:root {
--desktop: 1200px;
--laptop: 992px;
--tablet: 768px;
--mobile: 576px;
}

footer a {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a  i {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}

#footer {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

#copyright {
    border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 20%) ;
}

/* SMALL MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (min-width: var(--mobile)) and (max-width: var(--tablet)) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }

    footer li:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    footer i:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
}
/* MEDIUM MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (min-width: var(--tablet)) and (max-width: var(--laptop)) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }

    footer li:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    footer i:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
}
/* LARGE MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (min-width: var(--laptop)) and (max-width: var(--desktop)) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }

    footer li:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    footer i:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
}
```

```css
:root {
--desktop: 1200px;
--laptop: 992px;
--tablet: 768px;
--mobile: 576px;
}

footer a {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a  i {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}

#footer {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

#copyright {
    border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 20%) ;
}

/* SMALL MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (min-width: var(--mobile)) and (max-width: var(--tablet)) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }

    footer li:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    footer i:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
}
/* MEDIUM MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (min-width: var(--tablet)) and (max-width: var(--laptop)) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }

    footer li:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    footer i:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
}
/* LARGE MEDIA QUERY */
@media screen and (min-width: var(--laptop)) and (max-width: var(--desktop)) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }

    footer li:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    footer i:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    

    <!-- FOOTER SECTION START -->
    <footer class="bg-dark text-white " id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
            <h4>About Us</h4>
            <hr />
            <p>We are skilled IT professionals who specialize in solving a range of problems that our clients may face in the realm of IT.

            </p>
            <!-- FACEBOOK SECTION -->
            <a href="">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- INSTAGRAM SECTION  -->
            <a href="">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
            
            
            </a>

            <!-- TWITTER SECTION -->
            <a href="">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
              
            <!-- LINKEDIN SECTION -->
            </a>
            <!-- <a href="#">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
            </a> -->

            <!-- WHATSAPP SECTION -->
            <!-- <a href="#">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
            </a> -->
              
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
            <h4>Quick Links</h4>
            <hr />
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a> </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
            <h4>Privacy and Terms</h4>
            <hr />
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Terms & Coniditions</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">API Documentation</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
            <h4>Contact Info</h4>
            <hr />
            <p class="text-white">
              City, State 12345 <br />
              Call Us Now 123-456-7890 <br />
              example@email.com
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-dark text-white text-center py-4" id="copyright">
        Copyright &copy; 2023 . All Rights Reserved.
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- FOOTER SECTION CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the header _"Privacy and Terms"_ to wrap into 2 lines?

Comment: Tablet and laptop are both "mobile". And `col-md-3` will become a full column for screens < 768px. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/breakpoints/

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I mean I want "Privacy and Terms" column to line up with the other cp;umns

Comment: @j08691 I don't get what you mean by Tablet and laptop are both "mobile"

Comment: Try the CSS rule: `footer h4 { white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }`. It's probably not exactly what you want but the columns will line up. To prevent text from disappearing you can either make the text shorter or the column wider.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I added that property to the ```footer h4 { white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }``` to the Medium Media Query properties ```@media screen and (min-width: var(--tablet)) and (max-width: var(--laptop))``` and nothing happened

Comment: If you don't hide the rule away in one of those Media Queries it will work.

Comment: The issue is clearly caused by word wrapping. You could declare nowrap, but the text will overflow into the next column. You could shorten the title to "Privacy, Terms"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that your 'Privacy and Terms' heading wraps onto 2 lines at some screen widths.

Here are a couple of options.

(1) You could make the headings smaller so it doesn't wrap:

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/rNQRZQj

Here's the new CSS starting at line 157

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  footer h4 {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
  }
}
```

Or

(2) You could leave the font size of the headings the same, but increase the height of all of them so they are the equivalent of 2 lines high

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/eYQXxmW

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  footer h4 {
    min-height: 56px;
  }
}
```

In both of these examples, at line 158 of the CSS, I added a little top padding to the paragraphs in columns 1 and 4 so that the content in all 4 footer columns lines up

Comment: thank for the amazing answer i really appreciate it, I was wondering if you could please take a look at one of mu other questions that deal with responsiveness. This is the link to the StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843930/bootstrap-5-contact-form-not-responsive

Thanks for any help you can provide me if it isn't inconvenient for you.